# Correct methods to do source transformation

Tags: circuit-analysis

What are the conditions to check before doing a successful source transformation without any errors. Is this example correct--[image]
The source transformed-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No the example isn't correct, since the current source is dependent the source transformed voltage source will also be dependent. When you have a current source and a resistance in **parallel** that can be transformed into a voltage source and resistance in **series** and vice-versa. 
Have a look at this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_transformation

Comment: So because of dependent source it will not be valid

Comment: @user221808 Rather, because the dependent source is transformed into an independent source, it isn't valid. It's valid to transform a dependent source into a dependent source.

Comment: @user221808 just replace the independent voltage source with a dependent one, rest is correct.

Comment: @user221808 Kindly accept the answer if it answers your question